# Wait for forked process to open a window

Tags: scripting, x11, process, window, suckless-terminal

I'm trying to make a script like the following:

```
st -n dropdown &
pid=$(xdotool search --classname dropdown)
```

`st` is a terminal emulator

I'm trying to run some commands on the created st using xdotool. Unfortunately the commands after `st -n dropdown &` are run before the actual st terminal starts up so there is no pid. I can always just put `sleep 0.1` after but there are instances (on older machines for example) where it will take longer than 0.1 seconds for the terminal to start. Is there a way to wait for the terminal to start before executing the rest of the script?

The `wait` command doesn't work because it waits for the process to finish, which in the case of `st` is when it is killed which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

`xtoolwait` is a utility that launches an X application and waits until it has mapped its window.  It then returns control to the original shell session.

It is usually used from one's `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` file.

You may use it in your script like this:

```
xtoolwait st -n dropdown
pid=$(xdotool search --classname dropdown)
```

The second command will not start executing until `xtoolwait` detects that `st` has mapped its window.  Note the lack of `&` on the first line (it's not needed). This may offer enough delay for the second command to find the PID correctly.